# How can I make a mutating iterator that locks inner data until dropped?

Tags: multithreading, rust, iterator

My goal is to make a `NewType(Arc<RwLock<Vec<T>>>)` with a `many_iter_mut()` method that returns an iterator that holds a write-lock (`RwLockWriteGuard`) over the inner `Vec<T>`.

Thus the write-lock will be held by the `ManyIterMut` iterator until the iterator is dropped.  This is different from obtaining the write-lock for every call to `ManyIterMut::next()`.  (which I already have working elsewhere)

This is useful to enable callers to set many elements and read many elements simultaneously, but atomically.  So that readers will always see a consistent view from one batch of writes to the next.  (My prior impl of `ManyIterMut` fails a concurrency test.)

The problem is that I can't get the `ManyIterMut::next()` method to compile because of a lifetime issue.  The compiler doesn't seem to like that the `write_lock` is owned by the `ManyIterMut` rather than the `LockedVec` which is being iterated over.

Here's the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b509639665d49ba230b08809142b3d7e).

The code that generates an error is:

```rust
impl<'a, V, T: 'a> LendingIterator for ManyIterMut<'a, V, T>
where
    V: StorageVecWrites<T> + ?Sized,
    V::LockedData: StorageVecReads<T>,
    T: Copy,
{
    type Item<'b> = StorageSetter<'b, V, T>
    where
        Self: 'b;

    // This is the fn that won't compile.
    //
    // we can't change the fn signature, it is defined by lending_iterator::LendingIterator trait.
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item<'_>> {
        if let Some(i) = Iterator::next(&mut self.indices) {
            let value = self.write_lock.get_at(i).unwrap();
            Some(StorageSetter {
                phantom: Default::default(),
                write_lock: &mut self.write_lock,  // <--- this seems to be the problem.  Because it has &mut self lifetime, not Self::Item<'_> lifetime
                index: i,
                value,
            })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

and the error is:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:164:13
    |
148 |   impl<'a, V, T: 'a> LendingIterator for ManyIterMut<'a, V, T>
    |        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
161 |       fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item<'_>> {
    |               - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
164 | /             Some(StorageSetter {
165 | |                 phantom: Default::default(),
166 | |                 write_lock: &mut self.write_lock,  // <--- this seems to be the problem.  Because it has &mut self lifetime, not Self::It...
167 | |                 index: i,
168 | |                 value,
169 | |             })
    | |______________^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`
    |
    = note: requirement occurs because of the type `StorageSetter<'_, V, T>`, which makes the generic argument `'_` invariant
    = note: the struct `StorageSetter<'c, V, T>` is invariant over the parameter `'c`
    = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance

error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to previous error
```

So, what am I missing?  It seems like it should be possible.  or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```rust
> write_lock: &'c mut RwLockWriteGuard<'c, V::LockedData>,
> ```

This pattern (`&'a mut T<'a>`) is (almost?) always wrong. At allows using the data *at most* one time. See [Borrowing something forever](https://quinedot.github.io/rust-learning/pf-borrow-forever.html)
 for more.

The solution is to introduce another lifetime. This requires some fixups, mainly in `type Item<'b> = StorageSetter<'b, V, T>` to change it to `type Item<'b> = StorageSetter<'a, 'b, V, T>`.

Comment: You sir, are a hero.   With your suggested changes, it works.  [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0fdcea06df22e995a2b0880fe8215fac).   And I verified that my concurrency test now passes in the real code.   Thank-you very much!